# Julia LinearAlgebra.LAPACK.geev! does not return lvector

Tags: julia, lapack, eigenvalue

In Julia 1.5.0, a call to `LinearAlgebra.LAPACK.geev!` like

```
W, lv, rv = LinearAlgebra.LAPACK.geev!('V','V', tMatrix)
```

is supposed to return the three items: the matrix `W`, the right vector `rv` and the left vector `lv`.  The function in Julia returns in `rv` what GoLang and Python return on `lv`. In Julia, the `lv` is returned empty, like `lv = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0., 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]`